# Как организовать pagination Yii2 на технологии jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, yii2, pagination

ACTION:

```
 ....
 $query = Fashionjob::find()->orderBy('date2public', DESC);
 $countQuery = clone $query;
 $pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count(), 'pageSize' => 5]);
 $pages->pageSizeParam = false;
 $model = $query->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
 ....
 return $this->render('index', ['pages' => $pages, 'model' => $model]);
```

VIEW:

```
...
 <div id='content'>
 <?= $model ?>
 LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pages,]);
 </div>
 ...
```

Вообщем все работает по кассической схеме без проблем!

Потом я хочу обновлять часть страницы `<div id='content'> </div>` через технологию `jQuery.ajax()`.

JS:

```
...
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/bla/bla",
        data: { industries: industries, categories: categories, availabilities: availabilities, country:country, city:city, ajax_page: page},
        success: function(response) {
        $('#content').html(response);
        }
 ...
```

Как организовать так, чтобы передавалась `$pages` и обновлялся `LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pages,])`, т.е. работала пагинация на странице?

Может как-то организовать по другому?

Поделитесь опытом плиз.

Answer (score 0):

Использовать JQuery плагин [Pjax](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-pjax)